# NavigationBar title just changes once (not white again then going back)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I created a new project. I have a `NavigationController`. In the `RootViewController` I have a `containerView` with a table and just one cell. If I click on the cell I push a new `UIViewController`. So my `Main.storyboard` looks like this:

[image]

**What I want:**

I want first to have a white `NavigationBartitle`. Then pushing to `secondVC` I want to change the `NavigationBarTitle` to black. Then clicking on back the color should change back to a white title.

**What I've did:**

I did a custom `NavigationViewController`. There I was changing the func `willShow viewController`. In this I wrote the `titleColor` should change depending on which screen the `navigationController` changes to.

**My code:**

```
import UIKit

class SettingsNavigationViewController: UINavigationController {}

// MARK: - Controller Lifecycle
extension SettingsNavigationViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.delegate = self
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        guard let child = self.childViewControllers.last else {
            return .lightContent
        }

        return child is ViewController ? .lightContent : .default
    }
}

// MARK: - NavigationController Delegate Implementation
extension SettingsNavigationViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        let isSettingsContainer = viewController is ViewController

        let backgroundColor = isSettingsContainer ? UIColor.cyan : UIColor.white
        let titleColor = isSettingsContainer ? UIColor.white : UIColor.black
        let image = isSettingsContainer ? UIImage() : nil

        navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = image
        navigationController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .default)

        navigationController.transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { (context) in
            navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = titleColor
            navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = backgroundColor
            navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : titleColor]
        })
    }
}
```

**What happened instead:**

If I change the screen to `seconndVC` the `navBarTitleColor` changes black. If I click on back it stays black. But it should change to white.

**The complete project** I also uploaded to github: https://github.com/Sonius94/stackNaviTitle

Comment: whats the problem you are facing. Now its works as your need, i think

Comment: no. I Am on Settings. I click on pushVC so I land on secondVC. There the title color is black. Then I click on back I am at settings again and the title is still black and not white like it should @LalKrishna

Comment: It works for me on iPhone 6, iOS 11.1.2

Comment: thats weird. hm you downloaded my project on github or created it on your own? If its your own can I see your project? Maybe I can find the difference.

Comment: I forked your project. Thats it. Same code.

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution could be, add a SecondViewController and in your SecondViewController you should implement the following :

```
override func willMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
    super.willMove(toParentViewController: parent)
    if parent == nil {
        // Add your navigation bar appearance for FirstViewController
    }
}
```